# Is it possible to blur an Input value in the Cycles material node editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I saw [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material) on how to blur an image texture, but how can I blur a defined input like a Fresnel input? When you set the Fresnel node to a value less than 1, it becomes sharp. However the color distribution is ideal for what I want. I just can't figure out how to adjust or even add a blur to that output.

[image: Fresnel Example]

I also could see this being very useful for other inputs, like the Wireframe node. You can get the wireframe lines very easily, however the transition has no way to be controlled currently.

[image: Wireframe Example]

Comment: AFAIK this isn't really possible. The accepted answer to the other question works by tweaking the mapping coordinates (if you zoom in you'll be able to see a noise pattern). But not sure how that would apply to a fresnel node.. Can I ask what you want to do this for?

Comment: Specifically for a custom cartoon shader, but I run across this issue quite frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. The answer you linked works by adjusting the mapping coordinates, but this isn't possible with the fresnel node.

---

*Perhaps if we knew more about what kind of effect you were trying to get we could think of an alternate approach..*