# Applying compositor elements to environment mapping

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am making an environment map to use for making a skybox in Unity 5. I know how to but what I am trying to do is apply a gaussian blur to it in the compositor to apply to the environment map image. My compositor setting will apply to the rendered camera image but not the environment map image. My question is how do I apply compositor elements to the rendered environment map image.

And before anyone suggests it, I have already tried applying this after the fact in GIMP and it doesn't work well and shows seams. Trying to do this in Blender to get rid of them.

Thanks for reading :) .

Comment: Could you make a sphere with the projected image inside, then blur the material properties of that sphere? See here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material