# How to auto-paint on edges(corners) with a script? Detect corners like in "UV-smart project"?

Tags: scripting, texture-painting

I need to automatically paint a line on edges(*corners that covers normals too*) where normals have an angle more than %myValue%. So before I never tried something like that in Blender. Can you guys tell me how to do it?
First I need to set up an angle  like when you use "Smart UV project" you set up an angle for Unwrap so there is a function to detect that angles.
Do i need to write a script or Blender has a built-in function or plugin already?

p.s. generally this question comes to the "Texture Paint" mode where I want to automate the process.

Comment: Are you trying to automatically do something akin to Pointiness node in Cycles, getting the paint strokes onto the edges similar to Cavity Mask in texture paint? Why do you want to script this instead of using the tools that are there already - is there some outcome or desired result you can share in pictures here to describe your need?

Comment: Don't know about the methods and tools you mention here so I can't answer are they similiar to what i'm trying to do, have a few skill in Cycles.
Basically I'm trying to paint on edges to make for example metal material look brighter on the edges of my model like if it was abrasion, to make it more realistic.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't seen this before but it could help you determine if you still need to script this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55991/blurring-feathering-a-procedural-pointiness-mask

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i need. I actually googled it before your second answer and that's what i was searching for. Yeah and that link, thanks for this again. If you post it as an answer i will accept it.