# How to get material to be brighter around edges

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I am trying to create a low poly boxy rock model. I want to have the edges to appear brighter than the faces of the material.

Is there any easy way to do this? And how would I go about it?
I am a fairly new blender user- please provide detail in you answer :)

Something along the lines of this with less scattered roughness/noise outside of edges:
[image]

Comment: hard to do with Eevee but with Cycles you can use Pointiness for example, then bake and you can use Eevee: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-YzpMYboq0

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120915/edge-angle-dependent-material-apply https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32166/adding-surface-scratches https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55991/blurring-feathering-a-procedural-pointiness-mask/69306#69306