# Smoothing out hard edges on cycles material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, blur

I am working on creating a material, and have come to a small problem.
At some point in my shader I achive this result:

[image: Black-White representation of affected areas]

This is basically binary information, either black or white. For my case I am now trying to blur the transition between the black and white areas to achive a softer looking effect in the final result's displacement map. I want to be able to control how large the blur is (thinking of it as the thickness of an outline around the white spots).

I have already researched a fair bit on my own the past few days, but none of the examples I found seemed to apply to my case.

Comment: Watch: https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=23m58s

Comment: Read also these related links: [How to blur a texture node in cycles material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material/9428#9428) and [How to smooth or blur a procedural texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67779/how-to-smooth-or-blur-a-procedural-texture)