# Cycles Blur an Image Texture node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image

I've made a texture that contains dots I'd like to use as a puddle texture on a sidewalk. One thing I've noticed is that if you look at the puddles closest to the camera, you can clearly see the low-resolution:

[image]

Is there a node or node setup I could make that would allow me to blur this texture? Or, more specifically, the alpha of the texture? The puddles image is Black and white, and I have the alpha of that image feed as a factor into my node composition:

[image]

I'd prefer not to have to do this in an external program, because I have 399 images that I am going to put into an image sequence for this node.

Comment: Blur the image in the compositor. Then export it as a new image sequence.

Comment: @JoshSilveous You should watch Bartek Skorupa's video on texture coordinates. Much to learn there, included an answer to your question: [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=1402)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68978/29586) should allow you to blur the texture (including Alpha). However, for this technique to work you need to use considerably more render samples to smooth out the noise, so blurring the images themselves (in the compositor or using an external tool such as Gimp or ImageMagick) would be a more efficient solution.