# How can I put the compositor viewer node result back into Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am doing this experiment with Compositor Nodes and Cycles Nodes. There are times where I want to blur an image from Cycles and to bring it into Compositor, simply blur it and back to Cycles.

I have a feeling that this is not possible. But maybe there is a trick to be able to do this in a way that even though it is not realtime, it can be triggered and bake as needed?

A simpler test is if I am using Compositor, load an image, blur it or make adjustment and then export it into Viewer Node, is there in anyway I could ready that "Viewer Node" image into Cycles? -->  I tried this does not quite work, I am getting pink color.

Comment: Getting pink...
https://imgur.com/gallery/7df6Q

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71106/cycles-blur-an-image-texture-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do this with multiple Render Layers:

1. first layer renders or loads an image and blurs the result as desired
2. second layer renders the rest and composite it with the result of 1, either directly or by loading an image texture from file saved in 1.

example:
[image]

Comment: Sometimes with Blender I am not sure whether it is compositor rendering first and then Cycles at which order.

Maybe I could actually use 2 Blend files, where one is rendering out Image, and the other take the image... it's an idea suddenly pops on my mind.

Because at the moment, Viewer node seems to give output, but the data is not readable by Cycles somehow... a feature that might be possible to add.

Answer (score 1):

The results from the compositor's Viewer or Composite node cannot be used as textures directly (same applies for the results of the VSE). They would need to be saved as images on disk and those images applied as textures.

If you need to blur a texture, that can be done directly in cycles by manipulating the input vectors. Read [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material/68978#68978) for more details.

(also worth watching : [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss - Bartek Skorupa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0&feature=youtu.be&t=23m58s)

Depending on what you want to do, you could also use a Map UV node in the compositor along with an ID mask to feed the rendered image as in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21750/1853)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/compositing-video-layers-in-3d-space