# Procedural square shape in Cycles (with similar effect to Gaussian blur)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, procedural

### Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

Basically what I want to achieve is procedural square shape with ability to blur edges with similar effect to Gaussian blur.

I'm aware of [Cycles limitations regarding blur nodes](https://rightclickselect.com/p/general/Sgbbbc/cycles-blur-node), and also I'm familiar with method to [blur texture by noise](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material). This case could be different as I want to use this shape further in my node setup.

### What I have so far:

**Results:**

[image: all]

**Node setup for the first example:**

[image: nodes]

### Overview and problems:

1. This is desired result for "blur" effect. Problem with this one is if I change **Color Ramp** to **Constant** shape has still rounded corners. Also with bigger scale (**Scale** - 2 and **Color Ramp** Black position - 1)  it looks like this:

   [image: bad_blur]

Sadly shapes on edges aren't tiles, after scaling (and applying) mesh they are just white stripes.

Another problem is control over size of this shape.

2. This is just ok result. Nothing to add. Maybe only painful control.
3. This is Box blur effect, only upside of it is that it could be achieved only by changing **Color Ramp** interpolation to **Linear** from **Constant** (pt. 2).

The biggest problem here is that despite I can have the shape/effect I want, control over them (and the fact that they are separated setups) is horrible. For example - scaling from really small square to big one touching edges involves changing **Scale** in every **Mapping** node and also correcting **Color Ramp**.

### Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution using maths nodes to calculate distance from the square and the Gaussian distribution function.

[image: result]

The key here is for any point in the shader to calculate the closest point to the square. The square is defined by 4 boundary values - X-Min, X-Max, Y-Min, Y-Max.

To calculate the closest point that is still within the square we can simply use the Max and Min functions. ie,

```
closest-X = Min( Max(X, X-Min), X-Max)
closest-Y = Min( Max(Y, Y-Min), Y-Max)
```

To calculate the distance to this point (ie, the closest distance to the square) we can use Pythagoras

```
distance^2 = X^2 + Y^2
```

ie,

```
distance = sqrt(X^2 + Y^2)
```

For the Gaussian falloff we use the equation :

```
 intensity = 1 / (2^dist)
```

Bringing it all together produces the following material (note that I've omitted the 'sqrt' of the distance calculation - this gives a more pronounced falloff based on the square of the distance, rather than the plain distance) :

[image: material]

Adjusting the input nodes (X-Min, X-Max, Y-Min, Y-Max, Focus) will adjust the size and 'blurriness' of the square. Note that the Gaussian blur starts from the edge of the square - so the square is always maximum intensity with the falloff starting at its boundary. This means that the blur will always make it appear larger - adjust the boundary values to compensate whilst adjusting the Focus if this is not desired.

To tile multiple squares you can simply use a Mapping node and Modulo nodes to repeat the range multiple times :

[image: material - tiled]

Animating the mapping and various inputs can produce the following result :

[image: result - animated]

Blend file attached [image]

---

This can be used to generate procedural tiles as shown by this sample image provided by @cgslav :

[image]

Comment: Wow! I didn't wanted this to be tiled texture but now I can't stop playing with it. Couple nodes more and I was able to create tiles with bumped mortar, check here: https://imgur.com/ENIJW3s Now only figure out different gradient per tile and this will be complete solution for making tiles Substance Designer style :)

Comment: Nice - that's really effective as tiles. Adding variation per tile shouldn't be too complicated - would just need to 'Round' the coordinates to integers before feeding into a Noise texture. I'll try and update the answer with that later.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working node graph. I don't know if it mimics exactly a gaussian filter, but it looks better than the screenshots you posted.

Forgive me for the messy graph, I guess you will organize all this with groups and so on ;-).

It looks like this:
[image]

Node setup:
(you have input for U/V coordinates of the top left corner of the square, the width/height of the square, and the amount of blur)

[image]

"feather interval" node group:
(note that with the maximum and minimum nodes, the input a and b can be in any order)
(note also that I put a max node on the feather to avoid dividing by zero or negative values)

[image]

Basically "feather interval" is 1D function similar to a gate function ([wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function)) with smooth corners.
Than I combine 2 intervals for U and V by multiplying them.

Hope it will help you! :-)

[EDIT]

I added the divide and substract nodes just after the U/V nodes. So (u,v) is now the position of the center of the square.

[image]

Comment: It's really amazing, almost perfect! I have only one question though, is there any way to resize shape "from center", or maybe there is some constant correlation between Size and U/V values? I've "merged" U and V values to not to manipulate both of them but centering small square is pretty hard, bigger are easier to match the center, still it's just eyeballing.

Comment: Glad it helps ;-). I'm not sure to understant why you merged U and V, you don't want to be able to place the square anywhere?

Comment: It's nice to have full control over it but my main need is to have it placed in the center of a plane/face and doing it manually isn't so precise. I was trying to calculate some kind of proportion between size value and U/V but as an artist I'm completely math resistant sadly...

Comment: I added some nodes in the last screenshot to make u,v the position of the center.
If you want to center the square, you can now just put U=V=0.5.

Comment: Basically I just shifted u and v by half of the width. There's no too complex math here ;-).

Comment: Absolutely stunning result! And believe me it's not so obvious for me ;) I can't see any correlation between simple math equation and representing them by math nodes. This is really high on my to-do/learn list but I can't find any reliable source for it.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe try to see math nodes naturally, just like operations +, -, *, /. For example the divide node: first input is the number to divide, second input is the "divider", and the output is the result of the division. Here on the screenshot the first input is the width, the "divider" is 2, so the output is width/2. Then same with the substract node, the output corresponds to the first input minus second input.
Try with simple cases, and play with nodes :-). IMO playing by yourself is better than watching a tuto. And no need for doc because you probably know what a division is ;-).