# Making Rounded Tile Corner From Procedural Brick Texture

Tags: materials, procedural

i've found an old video tutorial on youtube about creating [Procedural Tile Material](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PobPKHuX8pM) and been able to followed it.

not satisfied with the node setup without the Principled BSDF shader, i've tried to make another nodes setup. although it still bothers me on the comparison of results, with the glossy shader and roughness node in the Principled BSDF, i like the solid colours randomness in the material.

[image: procedural tile material with principled bsdf attempt]

after that i went towards searching about making rounded corner tiles, procedurally.

and the only one i've found as a really good one was this of cgslav and Rich Sedman: [Procedural square shape in Cycles (with similar effect to Gaussian blur)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89511/procedural-square-shape-in-cycles-with-similar-effect-to-gaussian-blur)

problems for me, are; 
the discussion isn't started with procedural brick texture.
i am not really that good to understand complex maths nodes setup yet.
the setup in the discussion doesn't seem to show how to generate random tones/colours.

thus, i'd like to ask if there's anyway to adapt that method into this node setup with default procedural brick texture and principled bsdf. or, any other way as long as it could:

- generate random colours/tones and rounded corner also.
- have that nice gradient for bump/displacement as shown in Rich Sedman and cgslav result.
- have possibility to have displacement node without inflating the object's mesh.

this is the blend file i've got so far;

[image]

Comment: [This might help...](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50961/how-to-create-iridescent-glossy-tile-material/51003#51003)

Comment: @RickRiggs, actually i wasn't looking for iridescence material. thanks to let me know about that kind of material in blender.

Comment: Clarification - That was more for the random color part of your question

Comment: Nice advertisement

Comment: @Dr Blender, what advertisement?