# blur images in material nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, blur

I made the timbered parts for a timbered houses. In order to make them look more realistic I formed squares, subdivided them with two cuts in edit mode and then pulled the middle square outwards. To make the Part that lays behind make look darker, I added following node tree:

[image].

But now you can clearly see the squares. How can I change that? Could I maybe somehow use the blur or defocus node from the compositing Nodes?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material

Comment: By affecting the coordinates with a noise texture you can blur textures in the material nodes. **Watch Bartek Skorupa's video: [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss**](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=1439)