# Blurring HDRI maps in Blender 2.8 EEVEE

Tags: texturing, world, hdri, blur

How to blur HDRI images set to the environment? There is no definite way, I see many posts on the internet being quite misleading, like how to do it in compositing but it doesn't seem like it quite works.

In Cinema 4D, every texture you set to an material then to an environment object (sky) has a defaulted blur parameter, so you can "easily blur an HDRI" even though in theory you're blurring a material's texture.

I tried looking at compositing, film, with some tuts saying to do the work in compositing tab. Can anyone give me a definite 2019 answer to how to blur hdri environments directly inside blender? Without going to Photoshop I mean.

Comment: You can use a blur node in the compositor, but you would have to save your blurred hdri.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material

Comment: No I mean is there a way to directly see the blurred HDRI in eevee and using a parameter to alter the value of the blur.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the to render a Blurry HDRI, Try with Depth of Field.
But, if you need to blur de HDRI for the reflection, then use roughness inside the materials that you want to blur.

Hope that helps.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Just blur it via a node; the relationship of the scene referred intensities will hold up just fine. Save as an EXR and done.

Easily done using Nuke, Fusion, or Blender. Don’t trust Adobe to do anything properly.

Route the result to the mapping node and use it as your environment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using a lighting plugin for Blender called HDR Light Studio. It will even allow you to blur individual lights on a HDRI map, or if you want, a whole HDRI Map. The plugin can also be used to light your 3D scenes with area lights.

You can watch HDR Light Studio in action here:
[HDR Light Studio Xenon Drop 2 Launch Video](https://youtu.be/HBJ__xPpk48)

You can try the plugin here:
https://www.lightmap.co.uk/