# Feathering a shader at the edges of the seams

Tags: materials, uv, shaders

I am trying to make a dark rim around the uv-seams of a mesh i.e. making the seams of a cusion a little darker. Is there a way in Blender to use the uv layout and blur it a little to use it as a mask mixing two shaders?

So far I only managed to create this effect by making such a mask in photoshop. This is counterintuitive because the shader should be as procedual as possible.
[image: the material without the desired effect][image: the uv-seam of the mesh]
[image: the image used for masking the shaders generated with the exported uv-layout]
[image: the desired effect]

Is there any way to achieve this without using self made texture?

Comment: Hello :). Blurring a texture in Blender isn't particularly intuitive, but this thread could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9394/78972